# Custom annotation on MGLMapView (MapBox) in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, annotations, mkmapview, mapbox

I used `MKMapView` for drawing `polyline` and showing saved `polyline` and also custom annotations.

But now trying to replace `MKMapView` with `MGLMapview`.

Drawing `ployline` and showing default annotations successfully as shown in the previous `MKMapView`

But I stuck at how to show custom annotations like below.

Used **JPSThumbnailAnnotation** in MKMapView

[image: [1]]

My question is,

How can I show custom annotations like above image ?

Answer (score 0):

Create your custom Annotaion class in .h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface LocationAnnotaion : NSObject<MKAnnotation>
@property NSString * titile;
@property (nonatomic, readonly)CLLocationCoordinate2D  coordinate;
-(id)initWithTitile:(NSString*) titile AndCoOrdinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) locationCoordinate;
-(MKAnnotationView*)annotationView;
@end
```

im .m file write:

```
@implementation LocationAnnotaion
-(id)initWithTitile:(NSString *)titile AndCoOrdinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)locationCoordinate
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        _titile = titile;
        _coordinate= locationCoordinate;
    }
    return self;
}
-(MKAnnotationView*)annotationView
{
    MKAnnotationView * annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:self reuseIdentifier:@"LocationAnnotation"];
    annotationView.enabled = YES;
   // annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"location_sign_map"];
    return annotationView;
}
@end
```

Add annotation to map view

```
LocationAnnotaion *annotation = [[LocationAnnotaion alloc]initWithTitile:LOCATION_TEXT AndCoOrdinate:your_coordinate];
  [mapLocationView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

and in mapview delegate add

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[CCLocationAnnotaion class]])
    {
        CCLocationAnnotaion * myAnnotation = (CCLocationAnnotaion*)annotation;
        MKAnnotationView * view = myAnnotation.annotationView;
        view.centerOffset = CGPointMake(0, -view.image.size.height/2);
        return view;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Hope it will help .

Comment: Thanks for reply ...let me try

Comment: i would like to add different multiple images as annotation like shown in the image

Comment: you can modify this to achieve that, I just show you a way to create custom annotation ..hope it will give you an idea .

Comment: for multiple image,  add an uiimage property in .h file, in .m file add a new parameter call image and send it while initialization(store it on uiimage property) , and then annotationView function set image what you send in initialization time .